# Failed attempts to bypass "Rate limits" and other Twitter API errors

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, rate-limiting

My codes try to collect tweets about "cars" on 2014-10-01. In attempt to handle the rate limit or any other Twitter-related errors (ie. over capacity), I implement code at the end telling the program to stop and wait for 20min whenever a TweepError has occur.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as the script crashes and I can still see the rate limit error message. Please advice, thanks.

```
import tweepy
import time
import csv

ckey = "xxx"
csecret = "xxx"
atoken = "xxx-xxx"
asecret = "xxx"

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret,
    'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)

startSince = '2014-10-01'
endUntil = '2014-10-02'

searchTerms = 'cars'

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerms, 
    since=startSince, until=endUntil).items(999999999):

    try:
        print "Name:", tweet.author.name.encode('utf8')
        print "Screen-name:", tweet.author.screen_name.encode('utf8')
        print "Tweet created:", tweet.created_at

    except tweepy.error.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60*20)
        continue

    except tweepy.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60*20)
        continue

    except TweepError:
        time.sleep(60*20)
        continue

    except IOError:
        time.sleep(60*5)
        continue

    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the streaming API? It has no rate limits - https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview

Comment: Oh I didn't know streaming API doesn't have a rate limits. Though I do think getting previous-day API data is better for my project since 1) I am concerned if there is an internet breakage, the streaming will miss vast amount of data, whereas, to call the 1% previous-day tweets from API, I can retry if things have gone bad, 2) I don't actually need to stream the data since instantly getting the data is not needed for my current application.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your `try-except` statement happens independent of your call to the Twitter API. The `tweepy.Cursor` is what triggers the rate-limit error. Try including this line:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerms, 
    since=startSince, until=endUntil).items(999999999):
```

within your `try` and see if the `TweepError` is caught (it should be). You may need a small modification to get the cursor to continue from the proper location but it should be trivial.